# Why doesn't `systemd-run --user` enforce restrictions such as `ProtectSystem`?

Tags: systemd

If I run this as root, it correctly prints *touch: cannot touch '/tmp/test': Read-only file system*.:

`systemd-run --pty --property=ProtectSystem=strict /bin/bash -c "touch /tmp/test"`

If I run it as myself, in my user's service manager (`--user`), it no longer protects me, `/tmp/test` is created:

`systemd-run --user --pty --property=ProtectSystem=strict /bin/bash -c "touch /tmp/test"`

Why?

I think I'm missing a fundamental understanding of what "service manager" is in systemd. Systemd is going to be a big part of my (our) life, so I'd really like to understand it enough to be able to figure out the above. Is there a doc that explains this?

The context is I'm trying to sandbox an untrusted script (fetched via `npm`). Running systemd-run as root seems to be heading in the wrong direction, especially as our build system will use this. I could use `firejail`, but I already have systemd, and am familiar with the various sandboxing properties, so if at all possible I'd like to succeed with systemd-run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProtectSystem` and the other `Protect*` options use read-only bind mounts to enforce the protection.  This is something a non-root user can't do, so you can't do this in a (non-root) user session, only in a system session.